# How to edit (non-XML) configuration files with WiX-based MSI installer?

Tags: windows

This is my problem:

I have an already existing software. Customers will ask for a MSI installer in the near future due to the requirements of their IT-departments.
The current installer does several configuration during the setup by editing configuration files delivered with the installer. These files are just plain-text files, no XML files and no Windows INI files.

The new installer should be built with Wixtoolset. (with the latest version)

Do I have to write my own custom action for this editing?

Are there any existing addons available providing this feature - if yes, which one do you recommend?

EDIT: added more information:

The files are Java .properties files and contain information like database connection settings and several paths to installed components.

Doing the setup of the .properties file upon the first start instead of during the installation is NOT an option due to restrictions from the customer's IT-department and would require bigger changes in the existing software. (= too expensive)

Comment: What format are your configuration files written in? Could you please post an extract? What do they define? For instance do they define the name of the software etc?

Comment: They are .properties files for/from java.

Comment: Writing custom action DLLs is really really easy. I've created my share of them. And if you want, you could also make use of the [wcautil](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wcautil) library to make things _even_ easier.